# JSF selectOneMenu valud change not updating other fields ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

on valuechange event of select one menu component, i can see the changes applied to the model / java, but i dont see changes applied to input components on page.

when i do a F5, i see the changes but other data input by user gets lost.
i want to do a refresh without user loosing his data entered which is not submitted yet.
how can this be achieved using jsf ajax.

i am calling java code using f:valueChangeListener. for ajax i am using a4j:ajax

```
<h:selectOneMenu rendered="" value="" immediate="true">
 <f:selectItems value="" />
 <a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="@form" />
 <f:valueChangeListener binding="" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: can these settings prevent updated model values from rendering on input components. i tried with execute=@form and by removing immediate=true as well. i notice that as soon as value change event completes, foces goes to one another input selectonemenu component on the page. how should i try to solve this.

Comment: What's your backing bean scope? And what's with all the blank attribute settings in your view? `rendered=""`? `value=""`?